# TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-idle

I am receiving the error

```
TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable
```

When trying to run the following block of code

```
bonds_unique = {}
for bond in bonds_new:
    if bond[0] < 0:
        ghost_atom = -(bond[0]) - 1
        bond_index = 0
    elif bond[1] < 0:
        ghost_atom = -(bond[1]) - 1
        bond_index = 1
    else: 
        bonds_unique[repr(bond)] = bond
        continue
    if sheet[ghost_atom][1] > r_length or sheet[ghost_atom][1] < 0:
        ghost_x = sheet[ghost_atom][0]
        ghost_y = sheet[ghost_atom][1] % r_length
        image = filter(lambda i: abs(i[0] - ghost_x) < 1e-2 and
                       abs(i[1] - ghost_y) < 1e-2, sheet)
        bond[bond_index] = old_to_new[sheet.index(image[0]) + 1 ]
        bond.sort()
        #print >> stderr, ghost_atom +1, bond[bond_index], image
    bonds_unique[repr(bond)] = bond

# Removing duplicate bonds
bonds_unique = sorted(bonds_unique.values())
```

And

```
sheet_new = [] 
bonds_new = []
old_to_new = {}
sheet=[]
bonds=[]
```

The error occurs at the line

```
bond[bond_index] = old_to_new[sheet.index(image[0]) + 1 ]
```

I apologise that this type of question has been posted on SO many times, but I am fairly new to Python and do not fully understand dictionaries. Am I trying to use a dictionary in a way in which it should not be used, or should I be using a dictionary where I am not using it?
I know that the fix is probably very simple (albeit not to me), and I will be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Once again, I apologise if this question has been answered already

Thanks,

Chris.

I am using Python IDLE 3.3.1 on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 64):

`filter()` in python 3 does *not* return a list, but an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) `filter` object. Use the  [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) on it to get the *first* filtered item:

```
bond[bond_index] = old_to_new[sheet.index(next(image)) + 1 ]
```

There is no need to convert it to a list, as you only use the first value.

Iterable objects like `filter()` produce results *on demand* rather than all in one go. If your `sheet` list is very large, it might take a long time and a lot of memory to put all the filtered results into a list, but `filter()` only needs to evaluate your `lambda` condition until *one* of the values from `sheet` produces a `True` result to produce one output. You tell the `filter()` object to scan through `sheet` for that first value by passing it to the `next()` function. You could do so multiple times to get multiple values, or use other tools that take iterables to do more complex things; the [`itertools` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is full of such tools. The Python [`for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for-loops) is another such a tool, it too takes values from an iterable one by one.

If you *must* have access to all filtered results together, because you have to, say, index into the results at will (e.g. because *this time* your algorithm needed to access index 223, index 17 then index 42) only *then* convert the iterable object to a list, by using `list()`:

```
image = list(filter(lambda i: ..., sheet))
```

The ability to access any of the values of an ordered sequence of values is called *random access*; a `list` is such a sequence, and so is a `tuple` or a numpy array. Iterables do *not* provide random access.

Comment: So frustrating to remember when this language is OO and when it's procedural - why not `iterable.next()` instead of `next(iterable)`?

Comment: @Basic: `.next()` is the hook method, `next()` the stdlib API. Like `len()` vs. `.__len__()`, `str()` vs. `.__str__()`, etc. In Python 3 the `.next()` method has been renamed `.__next__()`; it was a mistake not to give it a special-method name. `next()` (the function) also lets you specify a default value to return if `StopIteration` is raised.

Comment: It'd be quite a lot more helpful if this answer explained a bit more about the differences between the filter result and a list, and how to convert from one another. This answer assumes that the user is familiar with semantics of lists and iterables in Python, OP explicitly mentions that he doesn't fully understand dictionaries, which hints that he doesn't fully understand lists or iterables either.

Comment: @kevr: agreed, this question has proven more popular than I anticipated at the time. I've edited the answer to cover iterables in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 44):

Use `list` before `filter` condtion then it works fine. For me it resolved the issue.

For example

```
list(filter(lambda x: x%2!=0, mylist))
```

instead of

```
filter(lambda x: x%2!=0, mylist)
```

Comment: From Martijn's and K. Kotagram's answer -- filter in python 3 returns iterable, not list; list(iterable) is converting it into a list, so then it is subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

```
image = list(filter(lambda i: abs(i[0] - ghost_x) < 1e-2 and abs(i[1] - ghost_y) < 1e-2, sheet))
```