# Installing requests-kerberos on Windows

Tags: python, kerberos

Is there any way to install requests-kerberos on Windows?

When I try to install it with pip I have the following error:

```
py -m pip install requests-kerberos

ImportError: No module named 'commands'
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-n8s_inn\kerberos
```

I would be grateful if anyone knew another kerberos module. I'm using Python 3.4 and Windows 8.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [commands module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) was deprecated in python 2.6.

Thus, the issue appears to be a problem with your `pip` installation, and not with `requests-kerberos`.

There are a few things you can try, but I would focus on ensuring pip is working correctly. While you could install the package manually, you are really just pushing the pip problem down the road until the next time you install a package.

#### Ensure pip is installed correctly.

Use the pip command to ensure you are running pip in the python 3.4 context: (Note, this is my output, yours will be different because you are on Windows and running 3.4)

```
$ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

Additional information about pip can be found [here](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#requirements-for-installing-packages).

#### Download and install manually

Download the package manually from the [pypi repo](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-kerberos).

- Download the .tar.gz
- Extract the tar.gz and run `python setup.py install`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amccormack. It seems my output version doesn't match with my current python version (3.4): `$ py -m pip --version => pip 6.1.1 from C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages <python 3.5>`. In addition to, I tried to install the package manually but I get the following error: `File setup.py, line 39, in get_version return matches[0].group<1> TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable`, What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: @bobafett What does your `py` link to? Based on your `--version` output, pip is being used in a Python3.5 dir, but in your question you say you are using Python3.4. Have you tried installing using Python3.4?

Comment: Hi @amccormack. Thanks for your answer. My py links to Python 3.5.0a4 `$ py --version Python 3.5.0a4`. It seems that Python 3.5 and Python 3.4.3 are installed in this machine. I have tried installing it using Python3.4 and Python 3.5 but I get the same error with both: `File setup.py, line 39, in get_version return matches[0].group<1> TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable`. I don't know what I should do to solve this problem.

Comment: @bobafett So I took a look at line 39 in `setup.py`. That error is caused because the `filter` function works differently in python 2 vs python 3. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15876294/228489) for more info.  You could attempt to fix the setup.py file, but I would guess that if install doesn't work in python 3, there may be other bugs as well. I would attempt to install it with python 2.7.  You may want to post an issue on the [requests-kerberos github page](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos/issues)

Comment: That was the problem! Thank you very much amccormack!!! I finally replaced this instruction: `matches = filter(lambda x: x, map(reg.match, fd))` by  `matches = list(filter(lambda x: x, map(reg.match, fd)))` in order to get a list and solve the problem. Again, thanks :D