# Filter SQLAlchemy query with Python 3.5

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have the following code, which work correctly with Python 2.7, but raise exception with Python 3.5.1:

```
away_games = [{'home_team_results': filter(lambda x: x.team_id == g.home_team_id, g.team_stats)[0].as_dict(),
               'away_team_results': filter(lambda x: x.team_id == g.visitor_team_id, g.team_stats)[0].as_dict()}
              for g in self.db.query(Game).filter(Game.visitor_team == team).filter(Game.season == season)]
```

Trace:

```
 for g in self.db.query(Game).filter(Game.home_team == team).filter(Game.season == season)]
TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable
```

I've seen the answer to similar question: [TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876259/typeerror-filter-object-is-not-subscriptable), but it didn't help. How should I rewrite my code?

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in  [TypeError: 'filter' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876259/typeerror-filter-object-is-not-subscriptable), in Python 2 filter returns a list, but in Python 3 filter returns an iterator. So I had to write:

```
next(filter(some code))
```

instead of:

```
filter(some code)[0]
```

So the valid code is:

```
away_games = [{'home_team_results': next(filter(lambda x: x.team_id == g.home_team_id, g.team_stats)).as_dict(),
               'away_team_results': next(filter(lambda x: x.team_id == g.visitor_team_id, g.team_stats)).as_dict()}
              for g in self.db.query(Game).filter(Game.visitor_team == team).filter(Game.season == season)]
```